# In Lift, making a JObject with an inline function

Tags: scala, lift, lift-json

It's common in JavaScript, particularly in jQuery, to have a function call with a literal argument and for a field of that argument to be an inline anonymous function. Like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#mylist").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        stop: function () { alert('Hello!'); }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to make such a call from Lift? This is as far as I've gotten:

```
"#jsonScript" #> Script(js.jquery.JqJsCmds.JqOnLoad(
    js.jquery.JqJE.Jq("#mylist") ~> js.JE.JsFunc("sortable", JObject(
        JField("placeholder", JString("ui-state-highlight")) ::
        JField("stop", js.JE.AnonFunc(js.JsCmds.Alert("Hello!"))) ::
        Nil
    ))
))
```

The compiler complains that `AnonFunc` is not a `JValue`, which is absolutely true: it's not. But in JavaScript a `function () {}` call is a legal value for a literal object field. How can I let Lift know that?

The long-term goal here is for the function body to eventually be a:

```
SHtml.jsonCall( JE.Call("jsFunction"), liftFunction _ )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use JsObj:

```
def render = 
    "#jsonScript *" #> js.jquery.JqJsCmds.JqOnLoad(
        js.jquery.JqJE.Jq("#mylist") ~> js.JE.JsFunc("sortable", js.JE.JsObj(
            ("placeholder", "ui-state-highlight"),
            ("stop", js.JE.AnonFunc(SHtml.jsonCall( JE.Call("jsFunction"), liftFunction _)))
        ))
    ).cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer I gave a while back to someone who wanted to integrate Lift with jquery autocomplete, which uses a similar callback method: [Lift - Autocomplete with Ajax Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043179/lift-autocomplete-with-ajax-submission/10045978#10045978)